# Difference in behaviour between $x = undef and undef $x

Tags: perl, garbage-collection

[`undef $x` is different from `$x = undef`](https://gist.github.com/mysz/5125381). I was under the impression that both would trigger garbage collection and free memory, but it seems `$x = undef` does not do so.

Is this a language bug? On doing `$x = undef`, shouldn't it free memory?

Comment: 'reference count' of what?

Comment: no; `$x`'s reference count is how many other things are referring to it, nothing to do with how the variable itself works.

Comment: @ysth You are right. Wasn't thinking. Reworded.

Comment: What do you expect to be garbage collected and how to you test for that? Also I'm unsure that Perl gives any guarantee *when* a garbage collection happens (if there is some garbage to collect).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No and no. Perl favours speed over memory usage by not deallocating memory you're likely to need again. If you want the string buffer to be deallocated, use `undef $x;`.

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'
   Dump($x);
   $x='abc'; Dump($x);
   $x=undef; Dump($x);
   undef $x; Dump($x);
'
SV = NULL(0x0) at 0x1c39284       <-- No body allocated
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = ()                      <-- Undefined
SV = PV(0x3e8d54) at 0x1c39284    <-- PV body allocated
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)              <-- Contains a string
  PV = 0x3eae7c "abc"\0
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 12
SV = PV(0x3e8d54) at 0x1c39284    <-- PV body allocated
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = ()                      <-- Undefined
  PV = 0x3eae7c "abc"\0           <-- Currently unused string buffer
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 12
SV = PV(0x3e8d54) at 0x1c39284    <-- PV body allocated
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = ()                      <-- Undefined
  PV = 0                          <-- No string buffer allocated
```

Comment: Is the deallocation of memory the only difference between the two?

Comment: No difference when $x is magical. The magic will remain in both cases.

Comment: So yes, I can't think of any other differences.

Comment: I've added annotations to the Dump output.

Comment: To be clear, neither `undef $x;` nor `$x = undef;` free `$x` itself.

Comment: You can *free* `$x` if you `undef *x`, `undef $::{x}` or `delete $::{x}`. Though those only work because `$x` is a global variable. (By *free*, I mean lose access to the previous storage location.)